# Cytoscape: Error 83, no JRE found Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, cytoscape, silent

We are a biotech company from which some users use Cytoscape.
We normally "rollout" or "deploy" software silently with PDQ Deploy.

Cytoscape has been working for quite a while until I updated to 3.8.2 version.
Now, I'm probably right this has something to do with Java.

Whenever I try to silently install it, I get "Error 83, no JRE found" so it aborts the install right at the start.
Silent parameter: -q

Weird thing is, I tried multiple Java instances on those PC's. I tried Oracle JDK16 & OpenJDK 16 while also changing the JAVA_HOME env to their respective folder.

JRE11 doesn't exist for end users either, should be within the JDK folders but the silent install keeps throwing "No JRE found" despite both Oracle JDK and OpenJDK installed and each have their env tested.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cytoscape 3.8.2 only supports Java 11 -- we don't yet support Java 16.  We typically test things with OpenJDK 11, if that helps.

-- scooter

Comment: That makes sense. Seems to have fixed the issue installing the OpenJDK 11! :)